# Changing css for WooCommerce Billing Fields

Tags: css, woocommerce

I want to change the CSS styling for the first page of my WooCommerce checkout page to make the font larger and increase the margins around the input box. [Here](http://www.pinkavocado.co/cart-check-out/) is my website:

I used the following code and put it in my child theme on style.css but it doesn't seem to work:

```css
.woocommerce-billing-fields label {
  font-size: 55px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #222222;
}
```

Changed the font size to 45px.

Am I putting the wrong code into my `style.css` folder?

Comment: What are you exactly wanting to change ? As the `..woocommerce-billing-fields` doesn't seem to exists.

Comment: The first page of my woocommerce checkout is where the customer fills in their phone number. I want to change the size of the text that displays on the input form.

Comment: seems like your selector is either selecting nothing or the wrong element.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work too. I think it doesn't exist. May I know what code to write to change that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add the `!important` keyword to ensure that the property overwrites any previously set property :

```
.woocommerce-billing-fields label{ 
    font-size: 55px !important;
    line-height: 23px !important;
    color: #222222 !important;
}
```